# ActiverRecord::QueryMethods Where spawn object comes from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am reading Rails source code of ActiverRecord::QueryMethods to understand how   SQL of eager_load created.

I have gotten a question. Where is `spawn` object comes from? Moreover, I would like to ask how do `eager_load`, `includes`, `preload` work.

## ActiveRecord::QueryMethods

#### rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb

```
module ActiveRecord
  module QueryMethods
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    class WhereChain

    #leave out some codes

     def eager_load(*args)
       check_if_method_has_arguments!("eager_load", args)
       spawn.eager_load!(*args)
       
       #-----------------
        Where spawn object comes from?
       #-----------------
     end
  end
end
```

It seems spawn_methods file does something but I can not find require file

## My guess 1 : ActiveRecord::SpawnMethods

#### rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/spawn_methods.rb

```
module ActiveRecord
  module SpawnMethods
    def spawn #:nodoc:
      clone
    end
  end
end
```

## My guess 2 : ActiveRecord::Associations

#### rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Associations
    class CollectionProxy < Relation

      def scope
        @association.scope
      end
      alias spawn scope
    end
  end
end
```

**If you have any advise to read code effectively, please give me some. I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The following `module`s are all included in `ActiveRecord::Relation`: (rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb)

- FinderMethods
- Calculations
- SpawnMethods
- QueryMethods
- Batches
- Explain
- Delegation

This is what allows you you to continually chain these methods together as they will always return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object.

So both your guesses are correct. When a `ActiveRecord::Relation` is returned it will use the `SpawnMethods` definition and when a `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` is returned it will use the `scope` definition aliased as `spawn`.

See the [`ActiveRecord::Relation` Code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L18) for more details.